# How to make key unique in nested map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
{'The Lord of the Rings'.split(' ').map((word, wordIndex) => (
  <View key={wordIndex}>
    {word.split('').map((letter, letterIndex) => (
      <Button key={letterIndex}>
        <Text>       
          {letterIndex}
        </Text>
      </Button>
    ))}
  </View>
))}
```

The output of this code:

> 012 0123 01 012 01234

How can I achieve this in ever increasing unique key pattern?

> 012 3456 78 91011 121314151617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the third argument in the first `.map()` (see `arr` below), calculate the length of all previous words (`arr.slice(0, wordIndex).join('').length`) and add that to `letterIndex`. See demo:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {'The Lord of the Rings'.split(' ').map((word, wordIndex, arr) => (
      <div key={wordIndex}>
        {word.split('').map((letter, letterIndex) => (
          <span key={letterIndex}>
            {arr.slice(0, wordIndex).join('').length + letterIndex}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got exactly the result I wanted